# AngularJS / SignalR passing around data

Tags: angularjs, signalr, signalr.client

I am creating a simple AngularJS with SignalR web chat application. I have many of the features working, however I want to create a maintainable means of recieveing messages as the server sends them out and so on. I am running into my last problem that I cannot seem to find a way from my SignalRData service back to the service it is sitting in. So my hierarchy is as follows.

1. SessionState
2. SignalRData

I have a controller on my chat view that is using the the SessionState service.

I have methods written in SignalRData that handle the receiving of messages from a server how do I send that data into an array stored inside of SessionState, so that my chat controller can use it to bind to ng-repeat to create a chat window?

All my code that is useful

SignalRData service section on receiving messages:

```
// Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    chat.client.incomingMessage = function (data) {
        console.log("New message from " + data.sender + ": " + data.message + ".");
    };
```

Also my object for this service:

```
// Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

    var State = {
        Connection:
            {
                Connected: false,
                Connection_Id: "",
                Method: "auto",
                chat: chat.client
            }
    };
```

What is going on in the SessionState service:
This has been simplified for viewing

```
var State = {
        Server: {
            DataService: SignalRData
        },
        Messages: {
            Chats: []
        }
    };
```

chat controller:

My original thought was I could share the chat.client object through my services and then in my controllers override the function, sadly this didn't work and so I am stuck trying to figure a way of getting the data from SignalRData into SessionState.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('Controllers')
    .controller('chat_Controller', chat_Controller);

chat_Controller.$inject = ['$scope', 'SessionState'];

function chat_Controller($scope, SessionState) {
    $scope.pageClass = "";

    SessionState.Session.ValidatePage("User");

    SessionState.Session.SmoothSlide("Heading");


    SessionState.Server.DataService.Connection.chat.incomingMessage = newMessage;

    function newMessage(data) {
        console.log("Testing");
    };

}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found that simply just using $rootScope within my services was the easiest way to broadcast my data between them.

I would like some input on this however.